# How to maintain user session after exiting app in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app using Firebase as backend.  My App implements Firebase-Authentication API using simple Email and Password login for authenticating.

Everything works fine except for one issue.  I would like to maintain the user session even after a user closes the App.

FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser? has all the user properties (ex: uid, email, token etc...) for the current user which works great.  The problem I noticed is that FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser? is not persistent.  So after exiting the app and launching again, it returns null.

I would not like to ask a user every time they open the app to login again. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Firebase automatically persists the user token in the iOS keychain. It's automatically restored when the app restarts. You can monitor for this with `addAuthStateDidChangeListener` (see the [Firebase Authentcation documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)). If that's not the problem, post the [minimum complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Firebase should already be keeping track of your user through app launches.

Your issue could be with using `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?` directly rather than the recommended approach.

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting a listener
>   on the Auth object:
>
> ```
> FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
>   if let user = user {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> By using a listener, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an
>   intermediate state—such as initialisation—when you get the current
>   user.

In my own application, I use both. If the user doesn't exist with the first method, it moves onto the second, and if that fails, present login/signup screen.

Comment: Ah!  I just tried this approach and you are absolutely correct.  I figured I had to be missing something.  Thanks so much for responding.

Comment: Where should I put this conditon? If not in login viewcontroller?

Comment: Wherever you like. Anywhere you need to get the current user. Personally I wrap all this code in my own classes.

Answer (score -2):

FirAuth has been renamed Auth

Please use latest Firebase pod