# need to link firebase anonymous account to google login or facebook login account on firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, swift3

I have a scenario in which I am login via anonymous using firebase auth and from anonymous login account I have added event as favorite items from the list of event, and now i want to login with google or facebook so that my favourite items never lost whenever I login the favourites items must get from that login account.

I am using for above scenario Firebase linking. but problem is that firebase linking work only one time for an anonymous account, if  I start again login with anonymously and add favourite event and now I use previous method like google for sign in and linking this anonymous account always got error that "credential already linked"

My code is below

```
let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)



        // sign with firebase auth
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error in authentication linking")
                print(error)
               }
print("successfully linked")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an error this the way it's supposed to work. When you sign a user in anonymously Firebase assigns a UID to that anonymous user. Once that user is linked to a proper account that account is assigned the UID from the anonymous user.

What you're doing is signing an existing user in anonymously, which assigns them a new UID. Then you're trying to link that UID with an existing account. The error you are getting is correct. The account credentials are already in use from the first time you linked the previous anonymous account.

Once a user creates an account (i.e. their anonymous account is linked) they need to continue to use that account.

This means you can either not let them sign in anonymously anymore or you can [just leave them signed in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37536673/7245977).

[Convert an anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account)

[Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking)